# Production and Development in WAMP

Tags: html, apache, xampp, wamp

I'm trying to output errors in WAMP, I know there's production and development mode's.

But how do you switch between the modes? How can i define that i'm now in development and now in production. Or am I getting this totally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you using same server for development and production? basically you may need to edit php.ini to configure error output on server level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two php.ini files packaged with WAMP: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. They are preconfigured with common settings for either development or production. Whichever one you rename to `php.ini` is the one that will be used.

If all you want to do is turn on error reporting, you can just edit whichever php.ini file you are currently using by clicking on the WAMP icon in your system tray and choosing `PHP > php.ini`. This will open the file in a text editor where you can change whatever config you want including:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

There is lots of documentation online and in the file for possible values for this.